# How to add p-values to odds ratio with logistic svyglm()?

Tags: r, tidyverse, survey

I am using the code below to get odds ratios and confidence intervals for my svyglm model.

```
model <- svyglm(y ~ x + covariate,
                 design = survey_design,
                 family = quasibinomial(link = logit)) 

exp(cbind(OR = coef(model), confint(model)))
```

I get the p-values when I use `summary`, however, this returns coefficients that then need to be exponentiated. How do I add these p-values to the odds ratio and confint table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a tidy method for svlglm objects in the **broom** package.

```
library(broom)
tidy(model, expo=TRUE, conf.int=TRUE)
```